# How do you pull the newest patch from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have some testing I would like to automate, but this requires pulling patches out of gerrit.  To make the automation more stable, I would like to pull the most recent patches out of gerrit.  That is, I want to pull what would become the branch head if all the patches in gerrit were merged into the repository.

Comment: Pulling seems to be not-possible (since these are not a part of git yet) but if you want to fetch changes (patches), probably i can help you out. And you can use the same for automation.

Comment: Gerrit patches are stored in git, and can be pulled.  Do you know of some way to list all leaf patches?

Comment: Pulling = fetch + rebase.

Comment: A pull is either fetch + merge or fetch + rebase, depending on the configuration. The former is the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a script to do it by using:

> ssh {host}:{port} gerrit query --current-patch-set {change} |grep ref

**For queries:**
**Kindly go through** https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html

Then you will get some refs:(lets take 90 in this case)

> git fetch origin refs/changes/90/{patch-id-from-script}
>
> git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD  #or: git checkout FETCH_HEAD

I hope t will fulfill your motive. If still stuck, somewhere i am open for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrealistic. Imagine that you have 100 pending changes. If you would want to merge all of these, you will end up in merge conflicts in like 99% of all cases.

You should instead create automated builds for every single change respecting its dependencies. This allows you to inspect the "what if this would be merged" situation, ideally evaluated through a CI server.

Comment: I just want to pull "the head" out of gerrit.  I suppose if there are N possible heads, then there could be some automated tie breaker, like "most recent leaf dependency".

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gerrit workflows in general? I'm not sure what you mean by "most recent leaf dependency".

Comment: Every patch exists in a tree of dependencies.  Leaf patches represent patches which have no other patches dependent onthem.

Comment: Okay.. and you have one such a leaf patch per open change in Gerrit. It's easy to build that state for a single change. But merging all leafs together (what you want to do, if I get you right) tends to end up in merge conflicts. I suggest to edit your question and add more details.

Comment: I don't want to do any merging.

Comment: So you only want to build the state of the latest patch set for each change? Have a look at the [Gerrit Trigger plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger). Either you use Jenkins to create your build, or you follow the same ideas of watching [ssh stream events](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9/cmd-stream-events.html)